# Laravel Eloquent query model which has exactly a number of association in a n-to-m relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-in

I have a project where I have the following Models :

- Products
- FeatureTypes
- Features
- Variants

And the tables and relationships are the following :

[image: Database Schema Diagram]

I have a request where I want to retrieve the `Variants` from a `Product` with some specific `Features`. 
A `Variant` can have 1 or many `Features` but I want to have all `Variants` if I give one `Feature`, and have a more specific search on the `Variants` if I gave more `Features`, until I have only one `Variant` which can have only one set of specific `Feature`.

Here's the code I have for now :

```
$variants =  $product
->variants()
->whereHas('features', function($query) {
    $query->whereIn('id', json_decode(request('features')));
})
->with('features', 'features.featureType')
->get();
```

The `request('features')` contains a stringified array with ids of `Features`.

I used Eloquent's `whereIn` method thinking that it would give me only the variants that have exactly all the `Features` given in the request.

But while checking the documentation again, I see that it will return any `Variants` that has at least one `Feature` given in the request which is not what I need here.

How can I make that Eloquent's query to return me only the `Variants` that are associated with all the `Features` given by the request ?

Thanks in advance for you help ! ;)

Comment: You can't use depthed whereHas it seems, I think you need to use several `joins` to build your query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`whereHas()` accepts a fourth argument with the number of rows:

```php
$variants = $product
    ->variants()
    ->whereHas('features', function($query) use ($features) {
        $query->whereIn('id', $features);
    }, '=', count($features))
    ->with('features', 'features.featureType')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you that was the missing part ! I thought I had to modify the whereIn method and not whereHas